# How to add new y axis label on heatmap at specific location using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am trying to add new labels on heatmap using ggplot2.
I succeeded in removing y-axis labels using

```
theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.line=element_blank(),
axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

And I tried typing axis command to add new label on heatmap.

```
 axis(4,at=c(2,3,7,9,10), labels=c(a,b,c,d,e))
```

However, it showed error message.

```
Error in axis(2, labels = c(1:22, "X", "Y"), at = c(1:24)) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

How to replace old label and make new labels on specific location at y axis?
And I hope to show categorical information on y axis.

Here is my original code

```
data <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x,y))
p + geom_point(aes(size=y)) + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.line=element_blank(),
axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())

axis(4,at=1:10, labels=letters[1:10])
```

What I am trying to do is similar to the below figure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scale_x_continuous` from `ggplot2`. The `axis` function is meant to be used with base graphics's `plot` functions. The ggplot way of doing what you want would be as follows:

data <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))

```
#Make y axis breaks
ybrks <- seq(from=min(data$y), to=max(data$y), length.out=10)

#Make y axis labels
ylabs <- letters[1:10]

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(size=y)) + 
     theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
           axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybrks, labels=ylabs)
p
```

Be sure to check `?scale_y_continous`

Comment: By the way, would you give me additional option code for drawing separation line on y axis?

Comment: @sejin, I have no idea what a `separation line` is. Could you perhaps post a link to a graph somewhere online that has that feature?